# Stand alone package installing for ActivePerl

Tags: windows, perl, package

I have a standard installation of ActivePerl. I need to install the package that is not included to the installation.

Is there any way to install the package without using ppm / CPAN? (it is supposed to be installed as part of other program)

**NOTE:** It supposed to work under Windows

Comment: Use the CPAN utility? `cpan YOUR::PACKAGE`

Comment: @TLP It is supposed to be installed as part of an another application.

Comment: So your question is how to install a package that should already be installed by some other unnamed application on your computer? Well, at least we know its Windows, that's a start.

Comment: What version of ActivePerl? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit? Do you have `nmake` or `dmake` installed? Does the package include any XS (and if so, do you have a compiler set up)? There are a lot of variables here - it may be a good idea to identify the library package.

Comment: What does "install a package" mean? A Perl distribution or `ppm` package (`.ppd`)? Or are you trying to write an installer for a module (e.g. .pm file) that doesn't have an existing installer (`Makefile.PL` or `Build.PL`)?

Comment: Also, why the ban on `cpan` and `ppm`?

Answer (score 0):

A Perl package is an ephemeral store of subroutines and package variables in memory. Perhaps you mean a Perl *distribution*?

1. First, install `cpanm` if you don't already have it.

   ```
   cpan App::cpanminus
   ```

   Yes, this works on Windows. No, you don't have to install a compiler. `cpan` will do that for you if necessary.
2. Then, install the distribution by passing its file name to `cpanm`. For example,

   ```
   cpanm IPC-System-Simple-1.21.tar.gz
   ```

   This will perform the required configuration, install the indicated prerequisites, prepare the distribution's content for installation (e.g. by building any files that need building), run the distribution's tests and install the distribution.